# При открытом label, автоматически закрывать его при закрытии бургера

Tags: jquery, menu, label, accordion

У меня есть меню с вложенными ссылками, при сворачивании схлопывает в бургер, когда мы открываем бургер меню и раскрываем вложенный список и если закрываем сам бургер, то у нас не закрывается открытый label и меню не уезжает вверх. Приложила фото, как это выглядит. Как правильно задать функцию, на автоматическое закрытие всех label при закрытии меню? Закинула весь код со стилями, чтобы было удобнее.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let headerBurger = $(".menu-burger__header");
  let headerBurgerMenu = $(".menu-burger__header + .header__nav");
  let imgBurger = $(".menu-burger_img");
  let imgBurgerMenu = $(".menu-burger_img + .header__nav");
  let imgActive = $(".avatar_img");
  headerBurger.on("click", function() {
    if (headerBurger.hasClass("open-menu")) {
      $("body").removeClass("fixed-page");
    } else {
      $("body").addClass("fixed-page");
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("open-menu");
    headerBurgerMenu.toggleClass("open-menu");
    imgBurger.removeClass("open-img");
    imgBurgerMenu.removeClass("open-img");
    imgActive.removeClass("img_active");
  });

  imgBurger.on("click", function() {
    if (imgBurger.hasClass("open-img")) {
      $("body").removeClass("fixed-page");
    } else {
      $("body").addClass("fixed-page");
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("open-img");
    imgBurgerMenu.toggleClass("open-img");
    headerBurger.removeClass("open-menu");
    headerBurgerMenu.removeClass("open-menu");
    imgActive.toggleClass("img_active");
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
}


/* АНИМАЦИЯ МЕНЮ */

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.topmenu {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.topmenu>li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.down:after {
  content: url(img/chevron.svg);
  margin-left: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
}

.topmenu li a:hover {
  color: #ef6705;
}

.header_link:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px -5px rgba(239, 103, 5, 0.6);
}

.submenu {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  min-width: max-content;
}

.menu>li {
  padding: 0 25px;
}

.topmenu>li:hover .submenu {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg);
}

.submenu li a {
  color: #7f7f7f;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 36px;
  padding: 0 25px;
  font-family: "Kurale", serif;
}


/* БУРГЕР */

.header_link {
  color: #242e31;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: block;
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
}

.header_list {
  display: none;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

.content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.content-wrapper {
  margin-top: 78px;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 34px;
}

.header__nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.acor-container {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 1130px) {
  .menu_home {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .acor-container {
    display: block !important;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .header_box {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    justify-content: end !important;
  }
  .container {
    justify-content: end;
    flex-grow: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    width: auto;
  }
  .header__nav {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background: rgb(245, 246, 246);
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.37);
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
    top: -300%;
  }
  .down:after {
    top: 9px;
  }
  .header__menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 34px;
    border-radius: 0 0 30px 30px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .header__nav.open-menu {
    top: 55px;
  }
  .header__menu li {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
  }
  .menu>li:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ef6705;
    transition: 0.3s;
    filter: blur(1px);
  }
  .menu>li:hover:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 150%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ef6705;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%, 0%);
    filter: blur(1px);
  }
  .menu-burger__header {
    position: relative;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ef6705;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  .menu-burger__header span,
  .menu-burger__header:after,
  .menu-burger__header:before {
    height: 2px;
    width: 60%;
    left: 7px;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 1px;
    background: #515758;
  }
  .menu-burger__header span {
    top: 16px;
  }
  .menu-burger__header:after,
  .menu-burger__header:before {
    content: "";
  }
  .menu-burger__header:after {
    bottom: 5px;
  }
  .menu-burger__header:before {
    top: 5px;
  }
  .menu-burger__header.open-menu span {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  .menu-burger__header.open-menu:before {
    transform: rotate(38deg);
    top: 16px;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }
  .menu-burger__header.open-menu:after {
    transform: rotate(-38deg);
    bottom: 16px;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }
  .content-wrapper {
    margin-top: 48px;
  }
  .fixed-pade {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  /* СТИЛЬ ЛК */
  .header_photo {
    width: 10% !important;
  }
  .header_right {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  .header__nav.open-img {
    top: 55px;
  }
}


/* СТИЛИ ЛК */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .header_right {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .burger_icon {
    display: block !important;
  }
}


/* Бургер ЛК */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .menu-burger_img {
    position: relative;
  }
  .img_active {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ef6705;
    border-radius: 20px;
  }
  .header_nav {
    display: block !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    background: rgb(245, 246, 246);
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.37);
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
    right: -100%;
  }
}

.header_nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}


/* Хедер*/

.header {
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 50px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.header_wrap {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.header_box {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.header_logos {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.logo1 {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.header_navigation {
  max-width: 720px;
  width: 100%;
}

.header_navigation>ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header_navigation>ul>li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navigation__link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  /* font-family: "Montserrat-Regular"; */
  font-size: 14px;
}

.singup_btn {
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Montserrat-Regular";
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000;
  padding: 5px 35px;
  border: 1px solid #ef6705;
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.singup_btn_img {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: 24px;
}

.singup_btn_img>img {
  width: 15%;
}


/* СТИЛИ ЛК */

.header_right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  align-items: center;
}

.header_link_lk {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.header_photo {
  width: 15%;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.burger_icon {
  display: none;
}


/* АККОРДЕОН в бургере*/

.acor-container {
  margin: 20px 0;
  display: none;
}

.acor_a {
  font-family: "Montserrat-Regular";
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: #000;
}

.acor-container .acor-body {
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 0;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: padding 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: "Montserrat-Regular";
  font-size: 14px;
}

.acor-container .acor-body p {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.acor-container label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 7px 20px;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 100;
  font-family: "Montserrat-Regular";
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
}

.acor-container input {
  display: none;
}

.acor-container label:before {
  content: "\276F";
  float: right;
}

.acor-container input:checked+label:before {
  transition: transform 0.35s;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.acor-container input:checked+label+.acor-body {
  height: auto;
  margin-top: -5px;
  color: #000;
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.acor_a_wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.acor-container label:after,
.acor_a:after {
  content: "";
  display: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ef6705;
  filter: blur(1px);
}

.acor-container label:hover:after,
.acor_a:hover:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 20%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ef6705;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%, 0%);
  filter: blur(1px);
}

.acor-container label:hover,
.acor_a:hover {
  color: #ef6705;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="header_wrap">
    <div class="header_logos">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/logo_vro.svg" alt="logo"></a>
      <img src="img/logo_rso.svg" alt="logo1" class="logo1">
    </div>
    <div class="header_box">
      <div class="container header__container">
        <div class="menu-burger__header">
          <span></span>
        </div>
        <nav class="header__nav">
          <ul class="menu header__menu topmenu menu_home">
            <li><a class="navigation__link" href="#">Главная</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="down navigation__link">О нас</a>
              <ul class="submenu ul_about">
                <li><a class="header_link navigation__link" href="#">Российские Студенческие
                                            Отряды</a></li>
                <li><a class="header_link navigation__link" href="#">Волгоградское Региональное
                                            Отделение</a></li>
                <li><a class="header_link navigation__link" href="#">Контакты</a></li>
                <li><a class="header_link navigation__link" href="#">Галерея</a></li>
                <li><a class="header_link navigation__link" href="#">Новости</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="down navigation__link">Мероприятия</a>
              <ul class="submenu ul_events">
                <li><a class="header_link navigation__link" href="#">Поиск по категориям</a></li>
                <li><a class="header_link navigation__link" href="#">Календарь мероприятий</a></li>
                <li><a class="header_link navigation__link" href="#">Мои мероприятия</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="down navigation__link">Вступление</a>
              <ul class="submenu ul_entry">
                <li><a class="header_link navigation__link" href="#">Как вступить</a></li>
                <li><a class="header_link navigation__link" href="#">Направления</a></li>
                <li><a class="header_link navigation__link" href="#">Отряды</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="down navigation__link">Трудоустройство</a>
              <ul class="submenu ul_job">
                <li><a class="header_link navigation__link" href="#">Общая информация</a></li>
                <li><a class="header_link navigation__link" href="#">Объекты</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <div class="acor-container header__menu topmenu">
            <div class="acor_a_wrap">
              <a class="acor_a" href="index.html">Главная</a>
            </div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="acor" id="acor2" />
            <label for="acor2">О нас</label>
            <div class="acor-body">
              <a class="header_link navigation__link" href="coming_soon_page.html">Российские Студенческие Отряды</a>
              <a class="header_link navigation__link" href="coming_soon_page.html">Волгоградское Региональное
                                    Отделение</a>
              <a class="header_link navigation__link" href="coming_soon_page.html">Контакты</a>
              <a class="header_link navigation__link" href="coming_soon_page.html">Галерея</a>
              <a class="header_link navigation__link" href="coming_soon_page.html">Новости</a>
            </div>

            <input type="checkbox" name="acor" id="acor3" />
            <label for="acor3">Мероприятия</label>
            <div class="acor-body">
              <a class="header_link navigation__link" href="coming_soon_page.html">Поиск по категориям</a>
              <a class="header_link navigation__link" href="coming_soon_page.html">Календарь мероприятий</a>
              <a class="header_link navigation__link" href="coming_soon_page.html">Мои мероприятия</a>
            </div>

            <input type="checkbox" name="acor" id="acor4" />
            <label for="acor4">Вступление</label>
            <div class="acor-body">
              <a class="header_link navigation__link" href="coming_soon_page.html">Как вступить</a>
              <a class="header_link navigation__link" href="coming_soon_page.html">Направления</a>
              <a class="header_link navigation__link" href="coming_soon_page.html">Отряды</a>
            </div>

            <input type="checkbox" name="acor" id="acor5" />
            <label for="acor5">Трудоустройство</label>
            <div class="acor-body">
              <a class="header_link navigation__link" href="coming_soon_page.html">Общая информация</a>
              <a class="header_link navigation__link" href="coming_soon_page.html">Объекты</a>
            </div>

          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>

      <form action="/login">
        <div class="header_right">
          <a class="header_link_lk" href="#">Личный кабинет</a>
          <img class="header_photo" src="img/lk.png" alt="avatar">
        </div>
        <div class="burger_icon">
          <div class="container header__container">
            <div class="menu-burger_img">
              <img class="avatar_img" src="img/avatar.svg" alt="avatar icon">
            </div>
            <nav class="header__nav">
              <ul class="menu header__menu topmenu">
                <li><a class="navigation__link" href="#">Профиль</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="navigation__link">Мой отряд</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="navigation__link">Мои мероприятия</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="navigation__link">Настройки</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пожалуйста, только кто такой умный открытие подменю привязал к input. Вам что дали задачу сделать максимально конченную разметку сайта?))
добавил лишь в jquery - accorCheckbox.prop('checked', false); и let accorCheckbox = $(".acor-container input[type=checkbox]");

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let headerBurger = $(".menu-burger__header");
  let headerBurgerMenu = $(".menu-burger__header + .header__nav");
  let imgBurger = $(".menu-burger_img");
  let imgBurgerMenu = $(".menu-burger_img + .header__nav");
  let imgActive = $(".avatar_img");
  let accorCheckbox = $(".acor-container input[type=checkbox]");
  headerBurger.on("click", function() {
    if (headerBurger.hasClass("open-menu")) {
      $("body").removeClass("fixed-page");
      accorCheckbox.prop('checked', false);
    } else {
      $("body").addClass("fixed-page");
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("open-menu");
    headerBurgerMenu.toggleClass("open-menu");
    imgBurger.removeClass("open-img");
    imgBurgerMenu.removeClass("open-img");
    imgActive.removeClass("img_active");
  });

  imgBurger.on("click", function() {
    if (imgBurger.hasClass("open-img")) {
      $("body").removeClass("fixed-page");
    } else {
      $("body").addClass("fixed-page");
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("open-img");
    imgBurgerMenu.toggleClass("open-img");
    headerBurger.removeClass("open-menu");
    headerBurgerMenu.removeClass("open-menu");
    imgActive.toggleClass("img_active");
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
}


/* АНИМАЦИЯ МЕНЮ */

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.topmenu {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.topmenu>li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.down:after {
  content: url(img/chevron.svg);
  margin-left: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
}

.topmenu li a:hover {
  color: #ef6705;
}

.header_link:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px -5px rgba(239, 103, 5, 0.6);
}

.submenu {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  min-width: max-content;
}

.menu>li {
  padding: 0 25px;
}

.topmenu>li:hover .submenu {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg);
}

.submenu li a {
  color: #7f7f7f;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 36px;
  padding: 0 25px;
  font-family: "Kurale", serif;
}


/* БУРГЕР */

.header_link {
  color: #242e31;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: block;
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
}

.header_list {
  display: none;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

.content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.content-wrapper {
  margin-top: 78px;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 34px;
}

.header__nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.acor-container {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 1130px) {
  .menu_home {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .acor-container {
    display: block !important;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .header_box {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    justify-content: end !important;
  }
  .container {
    justify-content: end;
    flex-grow: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    width: auto;
  }
  .header__nav {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background: rgb(245, 246, 246);
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.37);
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
    top: -300%;
  }
  .down:after {
    top: 9px;
  }
  .header__menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 34px;
    border-radius: 0 0 30px 30px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .header__nav.open-menu {
    top: 55px;
  }
  .header__menu li {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
  }
  .menu>li:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ef6705;
    transition: 0.3s;
    filter: blur(1px);
  }
  .menu>li:hover:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 150%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ef6705;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%, 0%);
    filter: blur(1px);
  }
  .menu-burger__header {
    position: relative;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ef6705;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  .menu-burger__header span,
  .menu-burger__header:after,
  .menu-burger__header:before {
    height: 2px;
    width: 60%;
    left: 7px;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 1px;
    background: #515758;
  }
  .menu-burger__header span {
    top: 16px;
  }
  .menu-burger__header:after,
  .menu-burger__header:before {
    content: "";
  }
  .menu-burger__header:after {
    bottom: 5px;
  }
  .menu-burger__header:before {
    top: 5px;
  }
  .menu-burger__header.open-menu span {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  .menu-burger__header.open-menu:before {
    transform: rotate(38deg);
    top: 16px;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }
  .menu-burger__header.open-menu:after {
    transform: rotate(-38deg);
    bottom: 16px;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }
  .content-wrapper {
    margin-top: 48px;
  }
  .fixed-pade {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  /* СТИЛЬ ЛК */
  .header_photo {
    width: 10% !important;
  }
  .header_right {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  .header__nav.open-img {
    top: 55px;
  }
}


/* СТИЛИ ЛК */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .header_right {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .burger_icon {
    display: block !important;
  }
}


/* Бургер ЛК */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .menu-burger_img {
    position: relative;
  }
  .img_active {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ef6705;
    border-radius: 20px;
  }
  .header_nav {
    display: block !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    background: rgb(245, 246, 246);
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.37);
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
    right: -100%;
  }
}

.header_nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}


/* Хедер*/

.header {
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 50px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.header_wrap {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.header_box {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.header_logos {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.logo1 {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.header_navigation {
  max-width: 720px;
  width: 100%;
}

.header_navigation>ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header_navigation>ul>li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navigation__link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  /* font-family: "Montserrat-Regular"; */
  font-size: 14px;
}

.singup_btn {
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Montserrat-Regular";
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000;
  padding: 5px 35px;
  border: 1px solid #ef6705;
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.singup_btn_img {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: 24px;
}

.singup_btn_img>img {
  width: 15%;
}


/* СТИЛИ ЛК */

.header_right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  align-items: center;
}

.header_link_lk {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.header_photo {
  width: 15%;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.burger_icon {
  display: none;
}


/* АККОРДЕОН в бургере*/

.acor-container {
  margin: 20px 0;
  display: none;
}

.acor_a {
  font-family: "Montserrat-Regular";
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: #000;
}

.acor-container .acor-body {
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 0;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: padding 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: "Montserrat-Regular";
  font-size: 14px;
}

.acor-container .acor-body p {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.acor-container label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 7px 20px;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 100;
  font-family: "Montserrat-Regular";
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
}

.acor-container input {
  display: none;
}

.acor-container label:before {
  content: "\276F";
  float: right;
}

.acor-container input:checked+label:before {
  transition: transform 0.35s;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.acor-container input:checked+label+.acor-body {
  height: auto;
  margin-top: -5px;
  color: #000;
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.acor_a_wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.acor-container label:after,
.acor_a:after {
  content: "";
  display: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ef6705;
  filter: blur(1px);
}

.acor-container label:hover:after,
.acor_a:hover:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 20%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ef6705;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%, 0%);
  filter: blur(1px);
}

.acor-container label:hover,
.acor_a:hover {
  color: #ef6705;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header">
  <div class="header_wrap">
    <div class="header_logos">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/logo_vro.svg" alt="logo"></a>
      <img src="img/logo_rso.svg" alt="logo1" class="logo1">
    </div>
    <div class="header_box">
      <div class="container header__container">
        <div class="menu-burger__header">
          <span></span>
        </div>
        <nav class="header__nav">
          <ul class="menu header__menu topmenu menu_home">
            <li><a class="navigation__link" href="#">Главная</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="down navigation__link">О нас</a>
              <ul class="submenu ul_about">
                <li><a class="header_link navigation__link" href="#">Российские Студенческие
                                            Отряды</a></li>
                <li><a class="header_link navigation__link" href="#">Волгоградское Региональное
                                            Отделение</a></li>
                <li><a class="header_link navigation__link" href="#">Контакты</a></li>
                <li><a class="header_link navigation__link" href="#">Галерея</a></li>
                <li><a class="header_link navigation__link" href="#">Новости</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="down navigation__link">Мероприятия</a>
              <ul class="submenu ul_events">
                <li><a class="header_link navigation__link" href="#">Поиск по категориям</a></li>
                <li><a class="header_link navigation__link" href="#">Календарь мероприятий</a></li>
                <li><a class="header_link navigation__link" href="#">Мои мероприятия</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="down navigation__link">Вступление</a>
              <ul class="submenu ul_entry">
                <li><a class="header_link navigation__link" href="#">Как вступить</a></li>
                <li><a class="header_link navigation__link" href="#">Направления</a></li>
                <li><a class="header_link navigation__link" href="#">Отряды</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="down navigation__link">Трудоустройство</a>
              <ul class="submenu ul_job">
                <li><a class="header_link navigation__link" href="#">Общая информация</a></li>
                <li><a class="header_link navigation__link" href="#">Объекты</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <div class="acor-container header__menu topmenu">
            <div class="acor_a_wrap">
              <a class="acor_a" href="index.html">Главная</a>
            </div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="acor" id="acor2" />
            <label for="acor2">О нас</label>
            <div class="acor-body">
              <a class="header_link navigation__link" href="coming_soon_page.html">Российские Студенческие Отряды</a>
              <a class="header_link navigation__link" href="coming_soon_page.html">Волгоградское Региональное
                                    Отделение</a>
              <a class="header_link navigation__link" href="coming_soon_page.html">Контакты</a>
              <a class="header_link navigation__link" href="coming_soon_page.html">Галерея</a>
              <a class="header_link navigation__link" href="coming_soon_page.html">Новости</a>
            </div>

            <input type="checkbox" name="acor" id="acor3" />
            <label for="acor3">Мероприятия</label>
            <div class="acor-body">
              <a class="header_link navigation__link" href="coming_soon_page.html">Поиск по категориям</a>
              <a class="header_link navigation__link" href="coming_soon_page.html">Календарь мероприятий</a>
              <a class="header_link navigation__link" href="coming_soon_page.html">Мои мероприятия</a>
            </div>

            <input type="checkbox" name="acor" id="acor4" />
            <label for="acor4">Вступление</label>
            <div class="acor-body">
              <a class="header_link navigation__link" href="coming_soon_page.html">Как вступить</a>
              <a class="header_link navigation__link" href="coming_soon_page.html">Направления</a>
              <a class="header_link navigation__link" href="coming_soon_page.html">Отряды</a>
            </div>

            <input type="checkbox" name="acor" id="acor5" />
            <label for="acor5">Трудоустройство</label>
            <div class="acor-body">
              <a class="header_link navigation__link" href="coming_soon_page.html">Общая информация</a>
              <a class="header_link navigation__link" href="coming_soon_page.html">Объекты</a>
            </div>

          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>

      <form action="/login">
        <div class="header_right">
          <a class="header_link_lk" href="#">Личный кабинет</a>
          <img class="header_photo" src="img/lk.png" alt="avatar">
        </div>
        <div class="burger_icon">
          <div class="container header__container">
            <div class="menu-burger_img">
              <img class="avatar_img" src="img/avatar.svg" alt="avatar icon">
            </div>
            <nav class="header__nav">
              <ul class="menu header__menu topmenu">
                <li><a class="navigation__link" href="#">Профиль</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="navigation__link">Мой отряд</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="navigation__link">Мои мероприятия</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="navigation__link">Настройки</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Хороший вопрос, наверно так вышло из-за того что все с миру по ниточки помогали)))
Спасибо вам огромное, вы всегда рядышком, когда мне нужна помощь!)